# Construction of an m-step function used in the Recursion Theorem

Tags: set-theory

In Introduction to Set Theory by Hrbacek and Jech, the Recursion Theorem is stated as:

For any set $A$, any $a\in A$, and any function $g: A \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$, there exists a unique infinite sequence $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$ such that

(a)$f(0)=a$;

(b)$f(n+1) = g(f(n) , n)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

--

The definition of an *$m$-step computation* function which is used in the proof:

A function $t:(m+1) \rightarrow A$ is called an *$m$-step computation based on $a$ and $g$* if $t(0) =a$, and, for all $k$ such that $0 \leq k < m$,
$t(k+1) = g(t(k), k)$.

--

Let $f = \bigcup \{t \in \mathcal{P} ( \mathbb{N} \times A) \text{| } t \text{ is an m-step computation for some } m \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

Then it is proved that $f$ is a function with the required properties.

---

**How is $t^n:(n+1) \rightarrow A$ constructed rigorously from the axioms?**

By induction $t^0 = \{(0,a)\}$, assuming $t^n$,  $t^{n+1} = t^n \bigcup \{(n+1,g(t^n(n),n)\}$, we can prove that it exists.

Intuitively:

$t^{n+1} = \{(0,a),(1,g(t^{n+1}(0),0)),(2,g(t^{n+1}(1),1))),...,(n+1,g(t^{n+1}(n),n))\}$, but this seems too self referential.

To simplify notation let $g(x,m)=g_{m}(x)$:

$t^{n+1} = \{(0,a),(1,g_0(a)),(2,(g_1  \circ  g_0)(a)),...,(n+1,(g_n \circ \dots \circ g_1 \circ g_0)(a))\}$.

--

Trying to construct it using the axiom schema of separation:
$t^n = \{p \in (n+1) \times A$ | $p = (0,a) \lor (m \in n \land p = (m+1, (g_m \circ \dots  \circ    g_0)(a)))\}$.

But this seems to me that while proving the Recursion Theorem which will be used to define arithmetic operations on $\mathbb{N}$, we use either some type of finite recursion, or we are composing a function $g$ m times, which feels like using arithmetic operations that are not yet defined.

Comment: The proof that for every $n$, a function $t^n$ with the right properties exists, is by itself a proof by induction. You know that such a function exists for $n=0$ (you can explicitly write it down). And you know that if there exists some such function for $n$, then such a function exists for $n+1$. There is no reason to expect that you can directly construct $t^n$ using the axiom of separation.

Comment: @jonathan I did provide a sketch of that proof. I think my confusion lies in treating $t^n$ as a set rather than a description that becomes a set when you plug in a natural number.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your confusion. For each $n$, there is a unique set that follows a certain property (which depends on $n$) and we call that set $t^n$.

Comment: @jonathan My understanding is that $t^n$ is not an actual set, and that's why trying to construct it rather than _just_ prove that such a set exists for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ was confusing. We can construct $t^0$ or $t^{101}$, and they are types of $t^n$, but I'm not sure whether a general construction of $t^n$ is a meaningful concept. It would be like constructing a general periodic function.